# What is the difference between () and (): in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been working with python (python 2.7) for a while and I have noticed that when setting functions, there is 2 different ways that they are set:

```
def main()
```

and

```
def main():
```

What is the difference between them? I am just curious. Also I do not know if it is different for Python 3.

Comment: Big difference. The first one is a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: You always need the `:` when defining functions.

Comment: FYI, it's the same for python 3 (your second question)

Comment: "I have noticed that when setting functions, there is 2 different ways that they are set"  <- where have you seen it done without the `:`?

Comment: That's weird because this book I have been following through with python does both throughout the book. Cool thank you for letting me know

Comment: @AJSKRILLA that's just errors in the book then :)

Comment: You might be mistaking a function call (e.g. `func()`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments,

```
def main()
```

**is a `Syntax Error`**

and

```
def main():
```

***is how you define your functions.***

> The code block within every function starts with a colon (:) and is indented.

*This is same for Python 2 and Python 3*

*However, you call your function like this:*

```
main()
```

*i.e without putting colon at the end.*

*Check this for further details:*

[Python Functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)